# How to change date format in VBA to dd mm yy?

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

So, I have a form, where the main idea is to show cases who have been completed between two dates. The user can pick two dates from datepicker. The format is EU, 01/03/2019, the problem is that in VBA the format is US, so it Returns wrong values.

Iv'e tried a lot of Format(date, dd....  and so on, but so far no success. Also tried alot solutions both from the net, and my VBA book. But there is something I am missing. And now i am stuck, and don't know how to move on. =)

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click()

    On Error GoTo myErr

    Dim strsql As String
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim x, i As Integer

    Me.btnCalculate.Enabled = False

    strsql = "SELECT Activity.DateDone, Activity.Job1 AS a0, Activity.Job2 AS a1, [Job1] Or [Job2] AS a2, Activity.Job3 AS a3, IIf([canceled],1,IIf([moved],2,0)) AS x " & _
        "FROM Activity " & _
        "WHERE Activity.DateDone Between #" & Replace(Me.txtDate1, ".", "/") & "# And #" & Replace(Me.txtDate2, ".", "/") & "#;"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)
    For i = 0 To 2
        For x = 0 To 3
            Me.Controls("txt" & i & x) = 0
        Next x
    Next i
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To 3
            If rs("a" & i) Then Me.Controls("txt" & rs("x") & i) = Me.Controls("txt" & rs("x") & i) + 1
        Next i
        i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


myExit:
    Me.btnCalculate.Enabled = True
    Exit Sub

myErr:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo myExit

End Sub
```

The result this code gives me, is all years Productivity, and not between the dates, asuming it changes day and months, so I hope there are someone wo sees the solution out there, thnx =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Format*:

```vb
"WHERE Activity.DateDone Between #" & Format(Me!txtDate1.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtDate2.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#;"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been using it wrong, but this solved it! MAny many thanx =)